# Is there any way I can optimize this R code?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, optimization

This is a code I'm trying to run in rstudio. I know the iterations are way too long. Is there any optimal/faster way to do this? I've been stuck for 4+ hours and it doesn't seem like finishing any time soon.

I'm trying to make a distance matrix between 415 cities and 3680126 monuments. To optimize, I am only comparing those monuments with cities which are present in the same country.

```
for(x in 1:3680126){
  for(y in 1:415){
    if(list2_cities$Country[y]==list1_POI$Country[x]){
      distance_matrix [x,y] <- ({POI$Longitude[x]-cities$Longitude[y]}^2)+({POI$Latitude[x]-cities$Latitude[y]}^2)
    }
    else{
      distance_matrix [x,y] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If those are truly latitude and longitude in a geospatial sense, then the first question I want to answer is: don't do it this way. Pythagorean theorem works well in cartesian space, but geocoordinates are not cartesian. Even if you aren't concerned with the correct units of the distance calculation, one degree latitude and one degree longitude are vastly different on most of the earth. I suggest one of the `geosphere::dist*` functions, depending on your need for precision.

Comment: @r2evans that makes sense. I was using geosphere but it was taking very long with that too. Any way we can do it in a lesser time?

Comment: Your two loops are performing 1.5 billion iterations, it is going to take some time using any method.  Thomas's answer below is a huge improvement.  I would suggest splitting your data frames by country and then `distm` function on the smaller datasets.  This will provide a performance improvement by avoiding calculating distances across country borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `distm` from package `geosphere`

```
library(geosphere)
d <- distm(list1_POI[c("Longitude","Latitude")],list2_cities[c("Longitude","Latitude")])
m <- +(outer(list1_POI$Country,list2_cities$Country,`==`))
res <- d*m
```

where

- the `distm` part gives the all paired distances between two cities
- the `outer` part provides a mask such that values for non-matched cities are set to `0`

---

If your desired matrix is sparse, here is another option

```
common <- intersect(list1_POI$Country,list2_cities$Country)
rl <- match(common,list1_POI$Country)
cl <- match(common,list2_cities$Country)
d <- diag(distm(list1_POI[rl,c("Longitude","Latitude")],list2_cities[cl,c("Longitude","Latitude")]))
res <- matrix(0,length(list1_POI$Country),length(list1_cities$Country))
res[cbind(rl,cl)] <- d
```

where you only need to locate the matched cities and calculate their distances.

Comment: Ultimately, though, this is calculating the distance for those we know we're about to discard, right?

Comment: @r2evans Sorry that it was a typo, thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @r2evans Yes, it calculates all distances as the first step, and then filters out values by unmatched cities.